# Math.Round: округлить число до 2 знаков

Tags: c#

Имеем число точностью 4 знака:

```
decimal testDecimal=14.7848M;
```

И хотим округлить его до двух знаков так, как нас этому учили в школе, справа налево. В результате должны получить 14.79:

```
Console.WriteLine(testDecimal);
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(testDecimal, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)) //14,78;
```

Но реальность отказывается совпадать со школьными знаниями, и начинаем ее под эти школьные знания подгонять:

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(testDecimal, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)) //14,785;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(Math.Round(testDecimal, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)) //14,79;
```

Comment: А что вам кажется удивительным? То, что постепенное округление не то же самое, что «в один присест»? Так это никогда и не считалось правдой. Очевидный контрпример: 1.46 -> 1, но 1.46 -> 1.5 -> 2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

У кого-то хромают школьные знания?

Есть округление вниз(функция Math.Floor()), округление вверх(функция Math.Ceiling()) и просто округление до ближайшего целого(функция Math.Round()).

В данном случае округление до ближайшего целого: если конечное число меньше 5 то происходит округление вниз, если больше или равно то вверх. Поскольку мы имеем число 14.78**4**8 и третья цифра меньше 5, то округляется вниз. Верный ответ 14.78.

Comment: @Alex Krass, ядрена кочерыжка, если бы не указали на то, что изначально задача неправильная из-за ошибки округления пользователем, я бы так и думал, что это особенность работы функции округления...

Answer (score 0):

В чем вопрос?

Если округлять 14,7848 до числа с двумя знаками после запятой, получится 14,78. Без вариантов.

Answer (score 0):

А зачем такие сложности? Если нужно округлить число **вверх**, то можно сделать так например:

```
public static decimal RoundUp(decimal number, int digits)
{
    var factor = Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Pow(10, digits));
    return Math.Ceiling(number * factor) / factor;
}

Console.WriteLine(RoundUp(14.7848M, 2));    // 14.79
Console.WriteLine(RoundUp(14.78424M, 3));   // 14.785
Console.WriteLine(RoundUp(14.12M, 1));      // 14.2
```

**Демо: [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l6Vmq7)**

А вообще посмотрите ответы от других пользователей. Ваши суждения об округлении чисел несколько странные.